# Prepare exercise failed - Unable to prepare exercise. Exercise type for support all Data Types in health services android

Tags: android, kotlin, custom-data-type

Good afternoon, is there a way to indicate an Exercise Type that supports all Data Types in android health services? I have visualized the following example but this one only works for the metrics of a single sport:
https://github.com/android/health-samples/tree/main/health-services/ExerciseSample
However, in my case I would like to be able to use running and swimming metrics in the same exercise. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Health Services supports [at most one exercise at a time](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/health-services/active#lifetime) across all apps on the device. Your app can only register one exercise update listener at a time, so you can only have an exercise type that supports a single sport and its associated metrics.